# OOP: How to dynamically extend functions in superclass

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, design-patterns

I have a base class `B` and 2 derived classes `D1`, `D2`.

```
class B {
    int commonFunc();
    virtual int specifyFunc();
}
class D1 : public B {
    int specifyFunc();
}
class D2 : public B {
    int specifyFunc();
}
```

Now I meet a requirement that i need to extend my base class function `commonFunc()`. Since i don't want to modify existing code in base class, i derived another class like:

```
class B {
    virtual int commonFunc();    // Change to virtual
    virtual int specifyFunc();
}
class B2 : public B {
    int commonFunc();    // A new commonFunc() to meet new requirement
}
```

However, `D1` and `D2` cannot use the new `commonFunc()` in `B2` except I modify the inheritance hierarchy.

Here is a possible solution i figured out

```
class B {
    virtual int commonFunc();
    virtual int specifyFunc();
}
class D1 : public B {
    int specifyFunc();
}
class D2 : public B {
    int specifyFunc();
}
class NewD1 : public D1 {
    int commonFunc();   // Overrided commonFunc() in base class
}
class NewD2 : public D2 { 
    int commonFunc();   // Overrided commonFunc() in base class
}
```

Since the `commonFunc()` in `NewD1` and `NewD2` are exactly the same, this solution involves a poor code-copy

I am looking for any design pattern or solution which can dynamically extend base class without much modification to existing class.

Comment: How about containment ? B2 contains in NewD1 and NewD2. The solution remains in B2.

Comment: *"i don't want to modify existing code in base class"* -- *"without much modification to existing class"* -- So, which is it? Without *any* modification? Or without *much* modification? And please quantify "much".

Comment: You need to clarify your question or use some placeholder pseudo-code to help us understand what you want.

Comment: How about using `virtual` inheritance?

Comment: I do not know C++, but that sounds like the Decorator Pattern.

Comment: Decorator pattern is exactly what I needed! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several solutions. Inheritance should only be used to factorize code for classes having the same responsability. This means that your class `Car` shouldn't inherit from a class `Logger` because you want some logging capabilities. This will determine which solution to choose.

**1. D1 and D2 have the same responsability than B**

Then a good way to have a more modular inheritance is the pattern [decorator](http://www.dofactory.com/net/decorator-design-pattern). This would allow you to do what you want. Just a little code to have an idea:

```
class B {
    virtual int commonFunc();
    virtual int specifyFunc();
}

class BDecorator: public B {
    B parent;
    B(B&);
    virtual int commonFunc(); // Implementation forward to parent.
    virtual int specifyFunc(); // Implementation forward to parent.
}
class B2: public BDecorator {
    int commonFunc();
    int specifyFunc();
}
class D1 : public BDecorator {
    int specifyFunc();
}
class D2 : public BDecorator {
    int specifyFunc();
}

// Use:
B b();
B2 b2(b);
D1 d1(b2);
```

**2. D1 and D2 have not the same responsability than B**

Then you should use composition instead of inheritance. This means that you should define a pure abstract class `D` (an interface) and make `D1` and `D2` inherit from it. Then, in the constructor of `B`, you can inject a `D`. (Yes in this solution, you have to change B a little, tell me if this is really a problem.)

```
class B {
    D d;
    int commonFunc();
    virtual int specifyFunc(); // Do something with d.
    B(D);
}

class D {
    virtual int func();
}
class D1 : public D {
    int func();
}
class D2 : public D {
    int func();
}

// Use with B, but you can use B2 (inheriting from B) instead:
D1 d1();
B b1(d1);

D2 d2();
B b2(d2);
```

*I apologize for my old C++.*

Comment: Glad if I could help you!

Answer (score 0):

`Interface Design (Program to an interface, not an implementation)`

You could avoid such implementation dependencies by using a common interface (pure abstract class) `IB`. 
You could change behavior (`commonFunc()`) 
by adding new classes (`NewB`) without changing existing classes.
Clients refer to the common interface and are independent of an implementation.

`Decorator Design`

If you can't do that or really want do extend the behavior of an object dynamically
at run-time, Decorator may help.
But Decorator can only add behavior before and/or after performing the old behavior.

See the following UML diagrams (if you aren't sure how to implement, please let me know).

[image: UML Diagram]

For further discussion see the GoF Design Patterns Memory for learning
object-oriented design & programming / Decorator / Design Principles (Interface Design)
at http://w3sdesign.com.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! I will use decorator to solve my problem. Thanks again!